# How to sort objects in Realm asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to implement logic for the user to sort the tableview in different ways. (names, creation date, and file size)

However, I can't figure out how to get my collection of Results to sort asynchronously. Either by querying the db to return sorted data like:

realm.objects(ScanResult.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "creationDate"),

or by sorting the collection itself.

I tried following the Realm documentation: https://realm.io/blog/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/

but now, I'm pretty sure the new reference to the scanResults I have, isn't affecting the original, aka nothing changes in my tableView after reloading.

self.scanResults is my Results or type ScanResult collection

help!!

```
func sortScansByName(completion: @escaping(() -> Void)) {
    let threadSafeScans = ThreadSafeReference(to: self.scanResults)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let backgroundRealm = try! Realm()
        var resolvedScans = backgroundRealm.resolve(threadSafeScans)!
        backgroundRealm.beginWrite()
        resolvedScans = resolvedScans.sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
        try! backgroundRealm.commitWrite()
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say 'sort asynchronously', what does that mean and why do you need to do that? Using `.sorted(byKeyPath` on results, as shown in your question, will sort the results 'live' so the data is always in the correct order. Also, what are you expecting that function to do? For the tableView, once results are loaded call tableView.reloadData so it will refresh itself. Anytime the data changes in the results object, say... an object is deleted, you would be notified in your observer and could reload the tableView. See [notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications)

Comment: @Jay, I am trying to let the user sort the elements of the tableview, but if I do it on the main thread, the UI freezes, and then pops when it is done. I want to show an activity indicator and sort it on a background thread. I've tried using the .sorted(byKeyPath and I have tried sorting the objects myself, but Realm doesn't allow you to pass objects through different threads, so I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: Hmm. Let's say you have a list of fruits, Apple, Pear, Banana, Grape and they are loaded from Realm, sorted by name: Apple, Banana, Grape, Pear. That results object will *always* be sorted by name. If that's what's being displayed and say the user drags Pear before Grape, you now have an unsorted list, you wouldn't be able to do that with a sorted results object. Are you using a Results object as your dataSource or copying it to an array? You may want to consider some kind of managed index property that defines how the data is sorted and would more easily allow for custom sorts.

Comment: @Jay, what I want is for the user to be able to sort the fruits by different criteria. There's a button that says sort, once the user taps that, it gives them three options: by name, by date created, and by size. I was originally copying the Results type to an array, but I decided to undo that and just use the Results collection type.

Answer (score 0):

Realm results can be sorted in a variety of ways. According the comments there's a button that allows the data to be sorted by name, date and size.

I don't know what the object looks like but let's use a simple example

```
class ScanClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var date = ""
    @objc dynamic var size = 0
}
```

and we'll create three ScanClass objects and store them in Realm

```
let s0 = ScanClass()
s0.name = "scan 0"
s0.date = "20191201"
s0.size = 100

let s1 = ScanClass()
s1.name = "scan 1"
s1.date = "20200115"
s1.size = 50

let s2 = ScanClass()
s2.name = "scan 2"
s2.date = "20190701"
s2.size = 12

//write the objects to realm
```

and we have a class results object to store the results in

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var scanResults: Results<ScanClass>? = nil
```

we initially load the results in and update the tableView to display them

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scanResults = realm.objects(ScanClass.self)
        self.scanTableView.reloadData()
```

and (per the comments in the question) suppose there's a button in the UI where the user can select how to sort the results. If the user selected "Sort By Name" the following code is run

```
self.scanResults = realm.objects(ScanClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
self.scanTableView.reloadData

scan 0 20191201 100
scan 1 20200115 50
scan 2 20190701 12
```

then if the user selects "Sort By Date"

```
self.scanResults = realm.objects(ScanClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: true)
self.scanTableView.reloadData

scan 2 20190701 12
scan 0 20191201 100
scan 1 20200115 50
```

lastly, if the user selects "Sort By Size"

```
self.scanResults = realm.objects(ScanClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "size", ascending: true)
self.scanTableView.reloadData

scan 2 20190701 12
scan 1 20200115 50
scan 0 20191201 100
```

Obviously if you want to remember what the user last selected to sort by that option could be stored in User Defaults or Realm so the next time the tableView is displayed it will automatically sort by their last selected option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! however, my issue here isn't getting it to sort. This solution will sort only on the main thread, causing the UI to freeze for a moment. I want it to sort on a background thread so the UI doesn't freeze.

Comment: Nope. It will not do that as you are loading fresh data and the objects are lazily loaded so it happens in the blink of an eye. You could additionally have  'master' results objects and then sub results objects that filter it in different ways. It's super fast and we have lists of hundreds of items that update instantaneously

Comment: Hm. For me it lags for about 1 - 2 seconds. My Results is set up just like yours, so it is lazy loaded.

Comment: @BrandonJF If it's taking that long, something else is causing the delay. The code in  your question does not look like the code I suggest - perhaps you changed it but our lists are often 20,000 items+ and sort instantly.